# Mobile browser that has image-blocking option

Tags: ios, web-browser, mobile

I like having the option to make it by default so that images are not displayed except on whitelisted sites. This is how I browse the Internet on desktop. What browser will let me do that on iOS, to block images by default except where permitted?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself (so I'm not posting it as an answer right now), but I think possibly Firefox with the uBlock Origin extension will allow you to do this on iOS (and Android).

Comment: I know on desktop Opera has this option, but I've not tried their mobile options.

Comment: You may want simply to pick the browser you like best for other reasons, and then try to find an extension for the behavior you want.  It is likely that you would find one

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Browser with Ublock-origin can help you, while firefox by  itself can block the images, if you use Ublock Origin extension you will have better control of you whitelist, plus you can also block ads.

If you prefer Safari browser then you can try the ORION Browser, its based on webkit (same as safari) and supports extensions so you can use Ublock with it too.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox browser for iOS offers image blocking within the settings, no add-on required. But Firefox image blocking is only way to browse internet without images that's available for free. Haven't tried those shady unpopular browsers though.